# Using different proxies for multiple clients of a software

Tags: networking, proxy, network-programming, socks

I have a situation where I need to run 20 clients of an executable. I have to assign different proxies to these clients for testing purposes. I had a proxy software which assign different proxies to different clients, i.e. a.exe, b.exe. But in this situation all executables have to be same name.

is there any proxy software or code to assign different SOCKS proxies to specific clients? Using PIDs or proxy pools maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign different proxies and proxy types *per connection* via java.net.Proxy.

Comment: can you give a little bit detail or navigate me to a strong tutorial?

Comment: @Bartu Try the Javadoc first.